# special characters in yalm.dump python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, rasa

I'm trying to save a file in yaml format with

```
with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
   yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

with data, a dictionary with this format:

```
data={"## intent:greet": ["hi", "hello" ... "hola"], "## intent:goodbye": [...]}
```

in order to use it as nlu in a rasa development.
The problem is that yalm.dump does not save the keys in an appropriate way because of the ## character.
it saves the file as

```
'## intent:greet':
- hi
- hello
```

instead of

```
## intent:greet
- hi
- hello
```

What could be the way to solve the ' ' characters and delete the : in key (## intent:AAA) row??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate a Markdown file with a YAML processor. That isn't going to work.

Mind that [Rasa 1.x used the Markdown format](https://legacy-docs-v1.rasa.com/nlu/training-data-format/#markdown-format), which used `## intent:greet` as heading, while [Rasa 2.x uses a YAML format](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/training-data-format/), which looks differently. You either use the 1.x Markdown format or YAML. You cannot generate the 1.x format with a YAML processor.

Comment: Any idea to save the Rasa 1.x Markdown format from python?

Comment: [mdutils](https://mdutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but I don't see why you wouldn't simply generate the content as string and then write it to a file.